# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-ssl-pinning:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, axios

I'm encountering an issue with the react-native-ssl-pinning library while running my Android application in React Native. Although it works perfectly fine in iOS, it fails to build in Android with the following error:

sql
Copy code
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-ssl-pinning:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'.
> Could not create task ':react-native-ssl-pinning:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

I've attempted to resolve this by manually linking the library. Here's what I've tried so far:

Manual Linking: Since react-native link isn't working, I've attempted manual linking. Here are the steps I followed for Android:

In android/settings.gradle, I added the following lines:

```java
include ':react-native-ssl-pinning'
project(':react-native-ssl-pinning').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-ssl-pinning/android')
```

In android/app/build.gradle, I added the following line in dependencies:

```java
implementation project(':react-native-ssl-pinning')
```

In MainApplication.java, I added the following import statement at the top of the file:

```java
import com.toyberman.RNSslPinningPackage;
```

And then added new RNSslPinningPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method.

Unfortunately, despite these steps, I'm still encountering the same error. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!